# How to validate field in datasource in Dynamics AX

Tags: validation, axapta, x++

I would like to make a validation connected with datasource with select query. How should I write a validate() method in field in datasource?

Comment: Did you take a look at some of the data source field validations that exist in the standard application (e.g. form SalesTable, datasource SalesLine, field CustAccount)?

Comment: Please mention what are the options you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate field of form datasource you need override `validate()` method of field datasource.

For example in your datasource In field you would like validate press right click / override method / validate. Here put your code, then save the changes.