# AX 2012 Clear Method

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a Table with: AccountNum, CouponCode and ItemId. I have a Form. I already have a code where I have a CouponCode for a specific AccountNum and a method to throw an error when you try to put another CouponCode in the form for that AccountNUm.

I have to do the following: If you enter an AccountNUm with the specific CouponCode and after that you change the AccountNum, the CouponCode will remain there even though it is invalid for that Account.

I have to find a method in order to see this bug and clear the row if the AccounNum is not good for CouponCode.

Comment: Data validation is usually done with the `validate` or `validateField` methods on tables or form data sources. Did you take a look at [How to validate field in datasource in Dynamics AX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486085/how-to-validate-field-in-datasource-in-dynamics-ax)?

Comment: You most also have another table, where you enter the coupon code. Did you make a relation on this tabel to coupon table?